# Error: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above but used Emulator version 4.2.2

Tags: android

Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

I have integrate Google Play Services and added all permission but map is not displayed.

Comment: Can you post what ever you have done so far ? Can you try it on a real device and see if its working ?

Comment: You are welcome to try checking "Use Host GPU" in the AVD Manager, but AFAICT the emulator does not emulate OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: No, I have not tried it on a real device.-beniMathew

Comment: I have also used "use Host GPU" in the AVD Manager but the same problem occurs.